# How does temperature affect the altimeter

Tags: weather, student-pilot, cfi

Hi Im having a time understanding Pressure levels as it relates to the altimeter.

The answer says. The limitation of the altimeter is that, On warm days pressure levels are raised higher than on a std day and the altimeter would read higher than actual altitude.

Can someone explain this please?

My take.

Pressure levels are determined based upon height and temperature, so on warm days the pressure level at 29.92 would be higher because of the air expanding and Im guessing that because of the expansion of air makes the altimeter feel as though its at a lower indicated altitude. But were actually higher than the altimeter than what the altimeter reads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are pressure levels raised on warm days?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/88721/why-are-pressure-levels-raised-on-warm-days) and see also [this image](https://www.aero-mechanic.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/7-3.jpg)